# Negative t-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have run a test on a treatment where the mean (of particular performance) after treatment is greater than that before and standard deviation has decreased. My t value is in the -22 area and I have not found a negative t value before. Should I just use the absolute value and check this agains the t-table, as in compare 22 against the critical value according to my DF and confidence level?

Does a negative t reflect a positive or negative effect?

Comment: The $t$ statistic will have precisely the same sign as the difference between the means. If the first mean is 42 and the second is 666 the difference is negative; if you flip them round it's positive. There is no meaning to the order in which you present the means. Doesn't your software produce a P-value automatically?

Answer (score 2):

The t distribution is two-sided and centered around 0, so it is possible to have a negative t statistics. What was the null hypothesis?